# slack api to invite an app to a private channel

Tags: slack, slack-api

i want to invite an app using the python slack client to a private channel .
Tried using :

```
web_client.conversations_invite(
    channel=channel_name,
    users= "AppID")
```

this is giving me the error

```
The server responded with: {'ok': False, 'error': 'cant_invite', 'errors': [{'ok': False, 'error': 'user_not_found', 'user': 'AXXXXXXXXX'}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `AppID` is not the same as the UserID. The App/Bot also has a UserID.

**To find the UserID:**

In slack:

1. Click on the users name and choose
2. "Show Profile". Then open the "..." menu and you see the option
3. "Copy Member-ID"